# Upload media on Twitter using Tweepy with Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to catch a picture from an Url and post it on twitter
But I got this error that makes me anxious.

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not JpegImageFile

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import tweepy

def get_picture(picture,file_path):
    full_path = file_path + '.jpg'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(picture,full_path)



def twitter_api():
    consumer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    consumer_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    access_token_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    return api



picture = (f"https://www.iheartradio.ca/image/policy:1.15731844:1627581512/rick.jpg?f=default&$p$f=20c1bb3")
path=r'C:\....\...\....\.......\images\.jpg'


text=("Youpi It works!")

get_picture(picture,"images/")
imageok=picture=Image.open(path)
twitter_api().update_status_with_media(text,imageok)
```

Will appreciate if anybody got a clue !

Comment: What line is causing the `TypeError`?  It's not clear from your code

Comment: This one `twitter_api().update_status_with_media(text,imageok)`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it expects path to image - so use `path` - you don't need `PILLOW`

Comment: you should also check if it works directly with `URL`. maybe you don't have to download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget `Pillow`. It needs path to image on disk (as `str`, `bytes` or `os.PathLike object`)

```
twitter_api().update_status_with_media(text, path_to_image)
```

but you put `Pillow.Inage` which is `JpegImageFile` and you have it in error message

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not JpegImageFile
```

---

Full working code

```
import urllib.request
import tweepy
import os

def get_picture(url, full_path):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

def twitter_api():
    consumer_key = os.getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY')
    consumer_secret = os.getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET')
    access_token = os.getenv('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN')
    access_token_secret = os.getenv('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    return api

# --- main ---

url = f"https://www.iheartradio.ca/image/policy:1.15731844:1627581512/rick.jpg?f=default&$p$f=20c1bb3"
#path = r'C:\....\...\....\.......\images.jpg'
path = 'images.jpg'

text = "Youpi It works!"

get_picture(url, path)

twitter_api().update_status_with_media(text, path)
```

---

And if you want to send file without saving on disk or generated with `Pillow` then it has option `file=` which can get open file or object `io.BytesIO` - and then you can put data from internet directly to `io.BytesIO` and use it without saving on disk

```
import urllib.request
import tweepy
import os
import io

def twitter_api():
    consumer_key = os.getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY')
    consumer_secret = os.getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET')
    access_token = os.getenv('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN')
    access_token_secret = os.getenv('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    return api

# --- main ---

url = "https://www.iheartradio.ca/image/policy:1.15731844:1627581512/rick.jpg?f=default&$p$f=20c1bb3"

text = "Testing module tweepy"

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
file_like_object = io.BytesIO(data)
              
twitter_api().update_status_with_media(text, 'fake_name.jpg', file=file_like_object)
```

---

Example which use Pillow to convert image to grayscale and send to twitter - all without saving files on disk.

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import tweepy
import os
import io

def twitter_api():
    consumer_key = os.getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY')
    consumer_secret = os.getenv('TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET')
    access_token = os.getenv('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN')
    access_token_secret = os.getenv('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    
    return api

# --- main ---

url = "https://www.iheartradio.ca/image/policy:1.15731844:1627581512/rick.jpg?f=default&$p$f=20c1bb3"

text = "Testing module tweepy"

data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
file_like_object = io.BytesIO(data)

image = Image.open(file_like_object)
#image.show()

grayscale = image.convert('L')
#grayscale.show()

file_like_object = io.BytesIO()
grayscale.save(file_like_object, 'jpeg')
file_like_object.seek(0)  # move to the beginning of file

twitter_api().update_status_with_media(text, 'fake_name.jpg', file=file_like_object)
```

Comment: Thx for your answers ! I will check that :]

Comment: After the test i got i new brand issue about the encode : 
`tweepy.errors.TweepyException: Failed to send request: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page - you will have more place for code and FULL error message. What did you try to send? maybe you tried to send some file in place of text, or you have text in different encoding.

Comment: Thanks you Furas, I will try to find the solution, then if i don't I will create a new question but I really appreciated :)

Comment: first you can use `print(...)`, `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))` to check what you have in variables.

Comment: The URL I have is a `<class 'str'>`

Comment: But now got this one :   `
  files = {'media[]': stack.enter_context(open(filename, 'rb'))}
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: [https://www.artic.edu/iiif/2/904ea189-c852-5f84-c614-a26a851f9b74/full/843,/0/default.jpg]'  `

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it seems you used URL instead PATH - but it seems it can't send directly URL and you have to download file

Comment: But, is it an obligation to download it ? I create a new question with the full project over there : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714657/tweepy-upload-media-error-api-from-the-art-institute-of-chicago-invalid-argum]

Comment: I checked in documentation and it works only with local files and you have to download it. But using `io.BytesIO` you can keep image in memory without saving on disk.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is with this line: `imageok=picture=Image.open(path)`

Is that just a typo?

Comment: The thing is, it save the picture but after that i can't use it, seems that tweepy doesnt accept like this `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not JpegImageFile`

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Tweepy, it just looks wrong to me that there are two equals signs in that expression.  Is it supposed to be like that?